# C#. ASP.NET. Реализация модульности

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, рефлексия, модули

Есть сайт на ASP.NET MVC 5.

Задумался о реализации различных "модулей" для него, например, на сайте есть регистрация, после отправки формы в контроллере выполняется ряд проверок, допустим требуется добавить валидацию Email на содержание в списке запрещенных или валидацию имени пользователя на наличие нецензурных слов.

Понятно, что можно сделать внутри обычные методы для этих проверок, но интересует можно ли сделать модулем, чтобы в контроллере в методе регистрации в нужных местах исполнялись бы методы всех классов через рефлексию, входящих в `namespace`, например `MySite.Modules.xxx`, где xxx - метод?

Для написания модуля будет условие: реализовать кастомный интерфейс `IMyModule`, который будет содержать метод валидации

Вот так я это вижу у себя в голове, хотелось бы узнать мнение правильно ли так делать и возможно ли выполнять методы классов входящих в определенный `namespace` через рефлексию

Может быть я изобретаю велосипед и это делается как-то проще... но я не знаю

Comment: Вам надо LoadAssembly, из неё (Assembly) берете модуль с индексом ноль. А там уже GetMethod и Invoke

Comment: Скорее всего вам нужен какой-нибудь IoC-контейнер. Например, MEF.

Comment: Посмотрите реализацию драйверов СУБД, например Firebird https://sourceforge.net/p/firebird/NETProvider/ci/75316e13889036a88d6d961037b6c8f3cd662712/tree/source/FirebirdSql/Data/FirebirdClient/FirebirdClientFactory.cs Они через точку входа Factory реализованы